# Unable to schedule reports to specifed time

Tags: apex, community, reporting, reports-api

Hi I'm new to sfdc i got a requirement like i want to schedule a report every evening.But the problem is i didn't find my required time frame in Preferred Start Time pick list.so,any idea for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limited number of concurrent reports allowed within the system. You are allowed one report to run per time slot. If you want to run a report daily then the time slow on each day must be free, otherwise it will not be available. I expect that you already have some scheduled reports running at this time during the week.

Comment: [Could be 1 or 2 per hour allowed, depending what Edition do you use](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_analytics_per_edition.htm&language=en)